# Forgot Password Link From OpenCart 2.x Admin Not Working

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I am using OpenCart 2.x version. How do I reset the Admin password from the UI and not from the database? I found some solutions using the database User table but I don't want to do like that.

Actually, this is not working from installation, so can someone tell me if OpenCart has not provided the forgot password functionality for Admin?

Comment: It has that facility.

Comment: Got solution need to comments this line:  if (!$this->config->get('config_password')) {
   $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('common/login', '', 'SSL'));
  }  from admin/controller/common/forgotten.php.and also replace a line $message .= $this->url->link('common/reset', 'code=' . $code, 'SSL') . "\n\n"; with line .$message .= $this->url->link('common/reset&code=' . $code, 'SSL') . "\n\n";    and also need to comment .if (!$this->config->get('config_password')) {
   $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('common/login', '', 'SSL'));
  } in script admin/controller/common/reset.php

Answer (score 1):

Was looking for this as well since I just installed the application 2 hours ago, I somehow goofed on writing down the password. Anyhow I found the solution from this site "[http://www.speckygeek.com](http://www.speckygeek.com/how-to-reset-opencart2-admin-password/)"

Basically you need to do the following few steps and need to know some SQL and the database as this solution is command line for the MySQL system.

1. List item
2. Login to your database server
3. Connect to your database
4. Locate your Admin account entry and remember it's "id"
5. Type the following command and hit enter

   UPDATE oc_user SET password='d1c194daffb03fc2653027c87f76a12a4eaeac5f', salt='x3x6r693j';

Congratulations: Your admin password is now set to **password**

Try it out and then CHANGE it in your OpenCart Admin page and don't forget it.